# Simple jQuery on SharePoint 2013 list stops working after filtering

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a little bit of jQuery I'm adding to a SharePoint page that colors a few table cells in a list.  When the page loads it works perfectly, but when the list is filtered, the code stops. What do I need to do to make it work after the list is filtered?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('table.red').closest('td').addClass('redBG');
$('.yellow').closest('td').addClass('yellowBG');
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this use SharePoint Client Side Rendering.
Here some tutorials from PnP: https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP/tree/dev/Samples/Branding.ClientSideRendering
but you can search google as well.

Code:

```
(function () {
    if (typeof SPClientTemplates === 'undefined')
        return;
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
        OnPostRender: [
          function (ctx) { DoStuff(ctx); },
        ]
    });
})();

function DoStuff(ctx) {
    $('table.red').closest('td').addClass('redBG');
    $('.yellow').closest('td').addClass('yellowBG');
}
```

Use this as external js file and add link to the file on JSLINK property of ListViewWebPart which display your List data.

Your `OnPostRender` functions will trigger on filtering and paging.

Answer (score 0):

This worked on a list in datasheet view but in order for it to work in standard view and datasheet after filtering I had to include both functions.

```
     (function () {
        if (typeof SPClientTemplates === 'undefined')
        return;
        SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
        OnPostRender: [
          function (ctx) { DoStuff(ctx); },
        ]
      });
      })();

     function DoStuff(ctx) {
       $('table.red').closest('td').addClass('redBG');
       $('.yellow').closest('td').addClass('yellowBG');
     }
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('table.red').closest('td').addClass('redBG');
   $('.yellow').closest('td').addClass('yellowBG');
 });
```